# How to make reactstrap modal open or close from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to open / close a reactstrap modal from a parent component button, but I cannot get it to work.

I am passing the state `isModalOpen` as a prop to the child `ModalExample` component, and it changes as shown in the debug text fields I made, but the modal does not seem to open.

Any help is appreciated. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/67wy5nqp/

```
const { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } = Reactstrap;

class ModalExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <label>
          (child) this.props.isOpen
          <input type="text" value={this.props.isOpen} />
        </label>

        <Modal
          isOpen={this.props.isModalOpen}
          toggle={this.props.toggleModalView}
          className={this.props.className}
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.toggleModalView}>
            Modal title
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.props.toggleModalView}>
              Do Something
            </Button>
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.props.toggleModalView}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: true
    };

    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen
    });
  }

  showModal() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpen: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ModalExample
          isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
          toggle={this.state.isModalOpen}
        />

        <br />
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.toggle}>
          Show Modal From Parent Component
        </button>

        <br />
        <label>
          (parent) this.state.isModalOpen:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.isModalOpen} />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SampleApp />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the state variable `isModalOpen` both as the variable indicating if it's open, and the function to use to toggle it. Use `this.toggle` for toggling instead.

```
<ModalExample
  isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
  toggle={this.toggle}
/>
```

You are also using the `toggleModalView` prop in the `ModalExample` component, but you are passing in the function as `toggle`, so you should use `this.props.toggle` instead. You are also passing in `isModalOpen` as `isOpen`, so you should use `this.props.isOpen` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalFooter, ModalHeader,ModalBody} from 'reactstrap';


class ModalExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modal: props.initialModalState,
            fade: true
        };

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal,
            fade: !this.state.fade

        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>TOGGLE</Button>
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}
                       fade={this.state.fade}
                       className={this.props.className}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>



                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class SampleApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ModalExample initialModalState={false} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

**This example getting call component modal from another component**
```